# Formatting in springfox-swagger2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui

I have made a Spring Boot web service that I am adding documentation to. I'm using the springfox-swagger2 library to add the documentation. For example, I have:

```
@RestController
@Api(description = "A long description of my API that needs to span multiple lines", tags = "My Endpoint")
public class MyEndpoint {
   // rest of code
}
```

The description for the endpoint is rather long. There's an ordering that the users need to follow and some key parameters that I'd like to point out to users in the documentation. Is it possible to add nicer formatting to the description in the @Api annotation?

Right now, it is inlined with the tag and output looks like:

"My Endpoint : A long description..."

Ideally, I'd be able to add some HTML or CSS formatting to it.

Thanks!

**EDIT per comment:**

I am using springfox-swagger2 version 2.7.0.

When I attempt to put markdown in my Api.description:

```
@Api(description = "#Heading \n Some description")
```

I get the following in my swagger.json:

```
{
   "name": "My Endpoint",
   "description": "#Heading \n Some description"
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Render html in springfox-swagger-ui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40261455/render-html-in-springfox-swagger-ui)

Comment: @Helen - awesome find! Thanks! This would be perfect for the ApiOperation's. The markdown does not work in the Api.description though.

Comment: What version of springfox are you using? What value of `description` have you tried and what Swagger JSON/YAML does it generate?

Comment: @Helen - updated. Thanks again.